# C# 3D : ZoomExtents does not do its job when called after HelixViewport3D childrens updated

Tags: c#, events, zooming, toolkit, helix

Sorry for my bad english.

I have the following XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="Project.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:HelixToolkit="clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" MinWidth="1024" MinHeight="768" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click"/>
        <HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D x:Name="viewport">
            <HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
                <OrthographicCamera Position="1, 1, 1"  LookDirection="-1, -1, -1" UpDirection="1, 0, 0" />
            </HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
            <HelixToolkit:DefaultLights/>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="elem0"/>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="elem1"/>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="elem2"/>
        </HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the following Button_Click :

```
private void Button_Click()
{
    elem0.Children.Add(visual...);
    ..
    elem1.Children.Add(visual...);
    ..
    elem2.Children.Add(visual...);
    ..
    viewport.ZoomExtents();
}
```

Everything (the draw process) works fine except the viewport.ZoomExtents() in Button_Click().
The Zoom Extent is not done at all.

The ZoomExtents method works if it is called some time after the HelixViewport3D's childrens have been updated. eg If i create a second button where I call only viewport.ZoomExtents() and I click on this button, then the Zoom Extents is done.
I have subscribed to all (useful) events of the Viewport and called there viewport.ZoomExtents(). I thought there was an event fired when childrens are "Changed"... but nothing worked...

I tried another solution I found here : [Helix 3D Toolkit - ZoomExtents method call works different than activating ZoomExtents through gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819543/helix-3d-toolkit-zoomextents-method-call-works-different-than-activating-zoome)
... but that don't work either (perhaps it worked long time ago but now not).

Do you have any idea to help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you solved the problem? I'm trying by passing a Rect3D as a bounding box to the ZoomExtents method... and I'm getting some good results. I just need to understand how the parameters works